# Windows Certificate Authority Server runaway issuing certs

Tags: certificate, rdp, certificate-authority, remote, desktop

In our environment, we have a Windows Certificate Authority server. We've distributed our CA to our folks, and generated some certificates with CSRs for internal websites. That works great. We tried to configure a GPO for our VMs to install the CA and also request and install an RDP certificate. I've followed some guides online, and I'm finding after about a month the server has just been nonstop issuing certificates. Every few minutes it seems. I now have well over 30,000 certificates issues when our environment only has 200 VMs. Has anyone seen this before? Is there anything I can check? I included some screenshots of the GPO we've configured.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would check if client is able to successfully validate its own RDS certificate. For example, export RDS certificate on a client VM and run `certutil -verify -urlfetch rdscert.cer` and examine output. In addition, a screenshot of General tab of RDS certificate template would be helpful

Comment: BTW, make sure that no principal has Autoenroll permissions on RDS template.

Comment: @Crypt32 - The verify passed successfully. I didn't see any glaring errors there. I did notice the RDP cert went into the Local Computer -> Personal -> Certificates folder rather than the Remote Desktop -> Certificates folder. I'll try and get a screenshot posted of the General Tab. Looking at permissions, "Domain Computers" & "Domain Controllers" both have Auto Enroll permission allow checked.

Comment: Edited the original post to add a screenshot of RDS General Tab

Comment: You MUST uncheck `Autoenroll` permission for all principals in ACL. Thanks to General tab, it looks ok.

Comment: Done, do you think that caused it to go nuts? Now I get to figure out how to revoke or delete all these 30,000 certificates...

Comment: yes, autoenrollment can cause this. RDS implements its own automatic renewal mechanism and gets mad when autoenrollment is enabled.

Comment: @Crypt32 It's fixed now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of posting the confirmed solution (I was suspecting on).

If you deploy RDS/RDP certificates using new dedicated RDS certificate deployment GPO, then you ***MUST NOT*** enable `Autoenroll` permissions on certificate template. GPO mechanism implements its own renewal process and goes into a conflict with Windows Certificate Autoenrollment mechanism.